# OOP: Designing a menu system

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, oop

I am currently trying to create a menu system for a game and cannot arrive at any really sound way to do it. There are several menu screens, each of them non-trivial, so that I would like to keep these as separate classes. The main problem I am having is passing control between these menu screens.

I tried building each of the screens as a singleton and call one screen from the other directly, ie. something like `[[MainMenu instance] display]` in Objective C. This is a bit messy, because (1) I have to write the singleton boilerplate code for each of the menu screens and (2) the classes get dependent on each other, sometimes I have to code around circular dependencies etc.

I thought about making the classes fully static to get around the instance management (which is a bit extra in this case, since there really is just one instance of each screen). But this also looks quite ugly, especially with Objective C having to “fake” class variables by declaring them `static`.

Then I thought about some “manager” class that would create the instances and pass the control around, but I am not sure introducing an extra class would solve the problem, especially if this class was to be named Manager :-)

I should note that I *do* have a working system, it just doesn’t feel very nice. By which I mean there is a bit of code duplication going on, if I am not careful the thing might hang, and so on. Any ideas? I am aware that this is underspecified, so that the discussion will probably be more of a brainstorming, but I am interested in the ideas anyway, even if they do not outright solve my problem.

**Update: Thank You all for the ideas. What I did in the end:**

I reworked the menu contents (buttons, graphics, etc.) to fit under one interface called `ScreenView`. This is a general interface that looks like this:

```
@protocol ScreenView

- (void) draw;
- (BOOL) handlesPoint: (CGPoint) p;

- (void) appearWithAnimation;
- (void) disappearWithAnimation;
- (BOOL) hasFinishedAnimating;

@optional

- (void) fingerDown;
- (void) fingerUp;

@end
```

Thanks to this protocol I was able to throw away all the specific menu screens and create a general menu screen that takes a list of subviews to display and handles all the presentation like drawing, transitions, events and such. This general menu screen does not get subclassed much, because most of the menu screens are happy simply displaying a list of subviews. This would be the V in MVC.

Then I also created a controller class that handles all the events for a certain menu screen. (Obviously the C in MVC.) The root controller class handles the instance management, transitions between menus and some other little things. Most of the menu screens get a customized subclass of the controller that handles the events from the buttons and other subviews.

The number of classes got up, but the code is much cleaner, does not repeat itself and is less prone to errors. The instance management is still not perfect, but I’m reasonably happy with the design. Once again, thank to all who answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the tricks I learned to decent design is always separate your data from your code.  This will do WONDERS for your specific problem.

By this I mean that the menu items (strings) and relationships between the menus should be stored somewhere either in an array or a separate file (and read into an array).

You then use this array to instantiate all your menu classes.

Once you recode it to work this way (I've done this with menus), all your code will fall into place,  you'll also factor out--90% of your menuing code (each menu will no longer be it's own class, just the same class instantiated with its own unique data.

The target of the menu items are stored in the "data" as well (as method pointers or class instances).

Answer (score 2):

I think a MenuManager class would be the way to go. You'd have one Menu base class which all the menu screens derive from, and the manager would have a pointer to the currently active menu screen. It could also, for example, keep track of previous menu screens for easy use of back buttons on menu screens in arbitrary menu screen calls. Maybe just use a std::vector for that so you don't have to recreate the previous menu screens when going back (this would also prevent loss of entered information, like in an Options menu with an Advanced submenu).

Answer (score 1):

Putting all the contents of the menus into a dictionary, dumping to a plist and reading each as necessary by the menu screens is likely the simplest route but in all honesty, you should consider taking a more MVC-centric approach to solving the problem.  The screens should be for presentation of data not the storage of it.  If you provide for a clean separation of the data from the views, the problem solves itself.